# Any valid way of using a div as a child of ul?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-lists, w3c-validation

I am working on building a custom "mega menu" using Bootstrap. Some of my sub-menu `UL`s will have multiple columns, so I would like to leverage the Bootstrap framework to define the column layout. Now, I know that using a `div` as a child of a `UL` is invalid markup, but is there any way I can approach this that would be valid?

Here's an example of the structure I would like:

```
<div class="menu-container">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a href="#">Top Menu Link</a>
            <ul>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <li><a href="#">Child Links</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Child Links 2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <li><a href="#">Child Links 3</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <li><a href="#">Child Links 4</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <li><a href="#">Child Links 5</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Always use <li> immediate to ul.  You can then add div inside li. That will work

Comment: `<div>` are a permitted child of `<li>`.  [li definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) allows [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content), which `<div>` is. You can't have `<ul><div><li>`, but you can certainly have `<ul><li><div>`

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is rather trivially “no”, unless you wish to take it very formally and answer “sure, just write your own DTD”. The question body asks “is there any way I can approach this that would be valid”, leaving it open what “this” is. You should rewrite the question so that it describes in sufficient detail how you want some data presented.

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving the `div`s out, and putting the `row` class on the `ul`, and the `col-sm-3` class on the `li`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that will not work for me because some of the columns will have more than one parent `li`, sorry, should have made that clear in my example.